# Merge columns with CSS add new columns to the end of table

Tags: css, merge, html-table

When I merge two or more columns with `colspan`, I notice a new columns added to the end of table, it is like `colspan` pushing columns rather then just merge theme. Is there any solution to merge cells without to see new columns added to the end of table.

Comment: jsfiddle plz? colspan never failed me. and btw its a html property instead of css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
td:nth-of-type(2n) {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table demos</title>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Col 1 + 2</td>
      <td>Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>3rd col missing in second row, so it looks like the browser is adding a column in row one, which it doesn't.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

You have to wrap the columns in each and every `<tr>`, including the table heading, if you're using one. Otherwise column numbers don't match in every row and the browser automatically fixes this.

Comment: Well, I thought colspan by merge will override the next column not just extend the current cell and display as two cells merged. Now thinks is clear to me.